# TypeScript references with scriptTransformer

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, typescript, bundling-and-minification

I'm trying to add a bundle that compiles a TypeScript file, with a lot of references, to a single javascript file.

This works fine when I use tsc `myfile.ts --out myfile.js`. Allthough I don't want to do this manually all the time when I make a modification. I want this to become part of the build process.

I've found a nuget package to compile TypeScript to JavaScript: http://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.Core

But this does not include the references. My bundle config looks like this:

```
var scriptBundle = new Bundle("~/Bundles/myscripts");

scriptBundle.Include("~/app/typescript.ref.ts");
scriptBundle.Builder = new NullBuilder();
scriptBundle.Transforms.Add(new ScriptTransformer());
scriptBundle.Orderer = new NullOrderer();

bundles.Add(scriptBundle);
```

Example typescript.ref.ts:

```
 /// <reference path="file1.ts" />
 /// <reference path="file2.ts" />
```

Should become

```
 var file1 = "Hello from file1";
 var file2 = "Hello from file2";
```

I have experience with Gulp/Grunt, for this project I'm not able to use these technologies. I have to use the MVC bundling mechanism.

Web essentiels is installed, but this also compiles file by file, is there a way to add the `--out` flag to web essentiels or the bundle config?

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to add the --out flag to web essentiels or the bundle config

Simplest if you just modify your visual studio project properties -> TypeScript tab -> generate a single javascript file.

Comment: Is this feature also available for VS2012?